# Am getting spawn ENOENT error in VS code while search

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project, am using VS Code as my code editor, while searching a function/text or anything on the whole project here recently am facing an issue like below, how I will sort out this? Is anyone faced the same?

Any idea?
[image]

Comment: I'm also facing the exactly same error on Ubuntu. How did you get it resolved?

Comment: @Krishna I uninstalled an unwanted package that's didn't work, finally uninstalled VS code and installed it again, that's fine now.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was a different issue. I was using vscode and at the same time I updated it to a newer version from terminal. After I closed the existing vscode window, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your machine or virtual machine. In my case it was a internal error of Ubuntu 16.04.

After restarting my virtual machine that error disapeared from the visual studio search.